# Ubuntu 18.04, 18.10 disconnecting from internet on Ethernet

Tags: 16.04, networking, 18.04, internet, 18.10

It's been happening randomly on Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04 and now the same happens on Ubuntu 18.10. My router is 100% fine, no disconnections on Windows. It happens randomly. What is worth mentioning is that after I reboot the system the internet comes back up and when I click Reboot it never reboots, it just freezes on the purple screen that reads Ubuntu 18.10 and the progress bar goes on endlessly forever and nothing happens. I have confirmed with my internet provider that my router is 100% fine.

Output of `lshw -C network`:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 06
       serial: 74:d4:35:b7:c0:58
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.0.52 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7100000-f7100fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
```

***UPDATE***

I have just got disconnected from the internet again and when I clicked "Reboot" the system would not reboot, it just got stuck on a black screen and nothing happened so the same issue continues to occur.

This is the out from the system log from around the moment I got disconnected. It happened at 00:07 and the last logs appeared to be registered at 00:05:31.

```
May  9 23:48:22 Home CRON[7191]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
May  9 23:55:01 Home CRON[7621]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
May 10 00:00:10 Home systemd[1]: Starting Rotate log files...
May 10 00:00:10 Home systemd[1]: Started Rotate log files.
May 10 00:01:10 Home avahi-daemon[1209]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.0.52 on eth0.
May 10 00:01:10 Home avahi-daemon[1209]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.52.
May 10 00:01:10 Home avahi-daemon[1209]: Interface eth0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 10 00:01:10 Home gsd-sharing[3239]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit rygel.service not loaded.
May 10 00:01:10 Home gsd-sharing[3239]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.service not loaded.
May 10 00:01:30 Home whoopsie[2622]: [00:01:30] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
May 10 00:01:30 Home whoopsie[2622]: [00:01:30] offline
May 10 00:01:31 Home NetworkManager[1208]: <info>  [1557439291.1038] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
May 10 00:01:31 Home dbus-daemon[1206]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.16' (uid=0 pid=1208 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
May 10 00:01:31 Home systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
May 10 00:01:31 Home dbus-daemon[1206]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
May 10 00:01:31 Home nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
May 10 00:01:31 Home systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
May 10 00:01:31 Home nm-dispatcher: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
May 10 00:01:32 Home org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2993]: [4431:4453:0510/000132.767330:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(413)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -137
May 10 00:02:21 Home org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2993]: [4431:4453:0510/000221.135841:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(413)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -137
May 10 00:03:31 Home org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2993]: [4431:4453:0510/000331.635348:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(413)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -137
May 10 00:05:01 Home CRON[7935]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
May 10 00:05:31 Home org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2993]: [4431:4453:0510/000531.731239:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(413)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -137
```

Comment: What type of connection: WLAN or Ethernet? Are there any messages in `demsg` or `cat /var/log/syslog` that are network related (e.g. from network manager)

Comment: I'm on Ethernet. What should I be looking for @SimonSudler?

Comment: Edit your question with the output of `sudo lshw -C network`. Report back.

Comment: I've added the output of `lshw -C network` now, @heynnema

Comment: @jedi status please...

Answer (score 1):

**1. Basics first, let's check your file system...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**2. Next, let's try a different ethernet driver, as the r8169 driver is known to have this problem in 18.xx...**

In `terminal`...

`sudo apt-get update` # update the software database

`sudo apt-get install dkms r8168-dkms` # install replacement driver

`reboot` # reboot the computer

Verify operation.

**3. Lastly, on the reboot freezes, hit the ESC key to see where it's hanging up.**

Comment: I've reinstalled the earlier version of the driver and will be monitoring the situation. Thank you.

Comment: @jedi please keep me posted

Comment: @jedi status update please/

Comment: I haven't had any issue so far but as I said, it happened randomly so ... I will keep monitoring the situation for the next month or so and will get back to you if I still have any issues.

Comment: I just got disconnected from the internet again. I have updated my question with system logs from around the moment I got disconnected. @heynnema

Comment: @jedi How do you feel about updating to 19.04? You can also check your BIOS... `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` to get the current version, then go to the manufacturor's web site and see if there's a newer BIOS available.

Comment: well, I had this problem on 16.04, 17.04, 18.04, now I have it on 18.10 so I have mixed feelings about upgrading to 19.04 especially given that with every new version of Ubuntu the developers cause more issues than they fix...

Comment: @jedi My 19.04 was cleaner for me than all previous upgrades. The results were better too. You should also check your BIOS, as per my previous comments, and we can always run a memory diagnostic just to eliminate that angle. Let me know if you need help with either.

Comment: I have a second computer at home and I've just noticed the disconnects still occurs so this is most likely an issue with DHCP on my network. Requested a technician visit, will report back.

Answer (score 1):

@jedi from your logs of May 10, especially this line: avahi-daemon[1209]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.0.52 on eth0, to me it sounds like your issue could be related to: [avahi-daemon and “.local” domain issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352237/avahi-daemon-and-local-domain-issues).

You could try either of these two solutions described in the Stack Exchange thread:

(1) Modify /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf

```
From: domain-name=.local

To: domain-name=alocal
```

Note: iOS devices may fail to "see" your PC.

(2) Change the domain name in your router, e.g. from local to lan. If you provide make and model of your router, we can help on how to change this in your router.

Comment: I have this line in `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf`
`#domain-name=.alocal`
It's commented out. Should I uncomment it and change it to `domain-name=alocal`?

Comment: @jedi if it's commented out already, no need to change it. You could try the next option of changing domain name in router settings.

Comment: What is the issue? Why am I being disconnected? Do I understand correctly that the avahi-daemon is bugged? I can see that I am not the only person having this problem so it should be reported.

Comment: @jedi the issue appears to be avahi-daemon using .local as domain name. So if your router using the same domain name, it would conflict with avahi-daemon. From Stack Exchange thread: `mDNS/DNS-SD is inherently incompatible with unicast DNS zones .local. We strongly recommend not to use Avahi or ​nss-mdns in such a network setup`. Happens in certain environment and conditions, so obviously not everyone is affected by this.

Comment: I have a Connect Box, model DDAP616019E4. I looked at the settings and didn't find any spot where I can change the domain name. Maybe I'd need to call my ISP. Will check.